# Get the FUSE version string

Tags: c, fuse

Is there a function that returns the FUSE version string?

`fuse_common.h` has `int fuse_version(void)`, which returns the major version, multiplied by 10, plus the minor version; both of which are derived from `#define` values. (e.g., This returns `27` on my platform). What I'm looking for, however, is some `char* fuse_version(void)` that would return something like `2.7.3`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you said yourself, the version is defined in `fuse_common.h`. If you don't want to use `helper_version`, as @Alexguitar said  you may just write a small program that does it -- but it seems that only the two first numbers (major and minor) are available:

```
#include <fuse/fuse.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

char* str_fuse_version(void) {
    static char str[10] = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
    if (str[0]==0) {
        int v = fuse_version();
        int a = v/10;
        int b = v%10;
        snprintf(str,10,"%d.%d",a,b); 
    }
    return str;
}


int main () {
    printf("%s\n", str_fuse_version());
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Note: you should include `fuse/fuse.h` and not `fuse_common.h`; also, you may need to pass `-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64` when compiling.

```
$ gcc -Wall fuseversiontest.c -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64  -lfuse

$ ./a.out
2.9
```

Answer (score 2):

In the source code of fuse in include/config.h you have:

```
/* Define to the version of this package. */
#define PACKAGE_VERSION "2.9.4"
```

Additionally, there's a function in lib/helper.c that prints it.

```
static void helper_version(void)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "FUSE library version: %s\n", PACKAGE_VERSION);
}
```

Edit:

I do realize that the package versioning strings are only for internal use so you're probably stuck with the major and minor numbers exposed by fuse_common.h . You'll probably have to write a function like @Jay suggests.

Comment: As this is a static function, with no corresponding header, I guess one is forced to use the major.minor pattern. I wonder if they'll accept a patch :)

Comment: [Merge request submitted](https://sourceforge.net/p/fuse/fuse/merge-requests/5/) :)